# NGINX is redirecting on HTTP application for every 302 request on HTTPS application

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, https

I have couple of application one running on HTTPS(**ssl.demo.com**) and other application on HTTP(**nossl.demo.com**),here how my configuration for each application look like

**https** on application (https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/572a1d8c70234d28d4e0)

**http** application (https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/d6ce43d529f5a4e275a7)

Now as per what I see every redirection i.e (30x response code) cause the nginx to redirect it to the http application

Example : -

When on  **https://ssl.demo.com** any 302 request(let say 302 to `/path1` ) cause the nginx the redirect the above path to **http://ssl.demo.com/path1** instead of **https://ssl.demo.com/path1** (The problem  is **that although the domain look good without the scheme**(http instead of https in above case) but the path is **internally served by to nossl application instead of ssl**)

Any Clue what need to be done over here ?

Comment: You have `proxy_redirect off` for what reason?

Comment: @alexeyten i believe that is it. thanks :)